# Sending a follow up email to prof and ask for the data availability

Tags: professorship, email, academic-life

I sent an email to a professor to share the data they published a paper on (and they are obliged to do it). It's been more than 2 weeks, he has not replied yet.

Should I send a follow-up email under the previous email to get that on the top?

What can I write in the email to make it short and formal? I can think of the following-

*Dear Prof Bob,
Following up to make sure this email didn't get buried. Could you please share the data with me?*

Comment: 2 weeks is a very short time, especially in the summer when many academics take vacations during the time they are free of teaching responsibility.

Comment: @BryanKrause, that is probably an answer. Or the core of one.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I can wait for some more days. In case I need to send an email, would the one in the question be fine?

Comment: Likely unnecessary question, but did you try to contact the journal as well? they may point you at the repository where the data are stored. Some journals are now requiring the data to be stored somewhere permanently, some institutions are providing the infrastructures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed email text sounds a little pushy because you are sending this to someone whom you do not know personally.

My suggestion:

"Dear Prof. Bob, I hope this email finds you well. I'm following up to make sure that the previous email does not get buried, as I imagine you must be quite busy during this period. I would be very grateful if you could share the data with me, related to your paper AAABB.

Hope I can receive a reply from you soon.

Best Wishes,

(Name)"